# Implicit conversion from String to Int in scala 2.8

Tags: scala, scala-2.8

Is there something I've got wrong with the following fragment:-

```
object Imp {
  implicit def string2Int(s: String): Int = s.toInt

  def f(i: Int) = i

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val n: Int = f("666")
  }
}
```

I get the following from the 2.8 compiler:-

Information:Compilation completed with 1 error and 0 warnings
Information:1 error
Information:0 warnings
...\scala-2.8-tests\src\Imp.scala
    Error:Error:line (4)error: type mismatch;
found   : String
required: ?{val toInt: ?}
Note that implicit conversions are not applicable because they are ambiguous:
both method string2Int in object Imp of type (s: String)Int
and method augmentString in object Predef of type (x:String)scala.collection.immutable.StringOps
are possible conversion functions from String to ?{val toInt: ?}
implicit def string2Int(s: String): Int = s.toInt

Answer (score 24):

What is happening is that Java does not define a `toInt` method on `String`. In Scala, what defines that method is the class `StringOps` (Scala 2.8) or `RichString` (Scala 2.7).

On the other hand, there is a method `toInt` available on `Int` as well (through another implicit, perhaps?), so the compiler doesn't know if it is to convert the string to `StringOps`, through the defined implicit, or to `Int`, through your own implicit.

To solve it, call the implicit explicitly.

```
object Imp {
  implicit def string2Int(s: String): Int = augmentString(s).toInt

  def f(i: Int) = i

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val n: Int = f("666")
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I hadn't realised RichString has been superceded. What I'm still confused by is that when I don't provide an implicit, the conversion via augmentString isn't found and a type error occurs. I'm trying not to use an explicit call because the type to convert to is provided by a type parameter in the actual method I'm trying to write.

Comment: RichString hasn't been superceded, it still exists. I don't know what is the deal with AugmentedString though. The problem is that the compiler doesn't know which ".toInt" method to call: the one on AugmentedString or the one on Int.

Comment: RichString still exists? I better get this delete key checked out.

Comment: @extempore It still exists in Scala 2.7, as indicated. I'm pretty sure. :-)

Answer (score 8):

There is **already an implicit conversion in scope**, from `scala.Predef`. You don't need to declare your own implicit conversion to add a `toInt` method to a `String`. You have 3 options (I'd go for the last one!):

- Change your method name to something like `asInt`
- Unimport the conversion in `Predef`
- Don't bother defining your own and use instead the `toInt` that comes bundled with the scala library

Note that scala will only make use of an in-scope implicit conversion if it is *unique*.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, unfortunately the implicit from Predef doesn't kick-in if I comment out my implicit above, it only appears to be in scope when the competition turns up ;-) 
The toInt option is fine but I was exploring a series of conversions from String in a method determined by a type parameter, one of them being String i.e. a no-op.

Comment: I'll have to try this tomorrow with 2.8. I use the `toInt` conversion in production code (i.e. using 2.7) all the time!

Comment: `Predef` implicit conversion from `String` to `Int`? I am aware of something in the opposite direction (any + string), but not of this. Was there ever such thing in Scala?

Answer (score 1):

I think I have a workaround.

If I create a RichString from the String argument, the implicit conversion occurs from RichString to Int using the implicit method I provide (this works for 2.7.x and 2.8). If I remove my implicit I get a type error.

```
object Imp {

  implicit def string2Int(rs: RichString): Int = rs.toInt

  def f(i: Int) = i

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val n: Int = f(new RichString("666"))

    println(n)
  }
}
```

I'm still confused as to why both implicits came into scope and clashed when I provided an implicit and as to why the Predef one didn't come into scope when I didn't provide one for String to Int. I suppose the question about an implicit conversion from String to Int remains open.